# Error CS0433: The type 'xxx' exists in both 'xxx.dll' and 'xxx.dll'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I copied a Project from **Visual Studio 2010** to **Visual Studio 2015**. The Project was Building successfully in Visual Studio 2010, but now it is giving me this error,

> Error CS0433: The type 'xxx' exists in both
>   'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\xxx\xxx\xxx.dll' and
>   'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\xxx\xxx\xxx.dll'

I tried deleting all the Temporary `ASP.NET` Files, and Cleaning the Solution but it did not help. This is a Web Site so there is no Bin Folder to delete.

I also tried adding `batch = "false"` to the Compilation Tag in the Web.Config, and it did not help too.

What is exactly is wrong? I do not understand why it is creating 2 copies of its ascx files .dlls, it cannot be the code because it is working fine in **Visual Studio 2010.**

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but are both .dll names the same or are they different?

Comment: Both .dll files have different names as Visual Studio automatically tagged them with some random names like xxxqwerty.dll and xxxasdfg.dll during the Build (But why create multiple copies?), but they are from the same and one file. To be exact, as far as I can see, they are affecting my .ascx files.